# Is it possible to reuse array variable in c#?

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I'm new to c# and i was wondering is it possible to reuse a array variable in c#?
For example,
I have the following code,

```
string[] contactAddress = { "123 abc street", "xyz road", "Sydenham", "Christchurch", "Canterbury", "8023", "New Zealand" };
driver.AddContactAddress(contactAddress);
```

The reason why i want this is to reuse `contactAddress` but with different values. the idea is to call `AddContactAddress()` with different values. Hope it makes sense.

I checked other questions, but it didn't seem to answer my question.

This is used for form testing. So some forms have many values
Since there are many values, i thought of creating an array passing the values rather an pass each variable/value. Was this a bad idea?

I'm using c# and selenium webdriver.

Comment: Is this a onetime thing?  Can you make two different arrays?  Or are you passing in different values constantly?

Comment: the idea was to pass different values whenever i want to use AddContactAddress . this is for selenium testing and i wanted to test different cases.

Comment: You don't actually need a variable at all, if this is all you'll be doing.

Comment: this is just an example, actually the form is really big.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Initialize it with different values like this:

```
contactAddress = new []{"xxx","yyy"};
```

Comment: You don't really need the `new []` part, do you? Doesn't C# let you just use `{...}`, like in the question?

Comment: no it doesn't for some reason. i tried that before posting the question here.

Comment: @Jeff: You can say `int[] x = {1, 2, 3};` or `int[] x; x = new[] {1, 2, 3};` but strangely enough, you cannot say `int x[]; x = {1, 2, 3};`.  It's one of the quirks of C#.

Comment: @Jeff: You're welcome. Coincidentally, this fact is the subject of my blog this week; I think the post is scheduled to go up on Thursday.

Comment: int[] x = {1, 2, 3}  is called inline initialization. However if you declare it and never initialized it like int []x , then in order to have objects in it , you have to create the array object . Either you can do x= new [] {1,2}  or x= new int[] {1,2,3}